# How to use the property of an object for a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the `var dir= director` to refer to the property `"director":"Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin.",` How can I do that? I'm new to Javascript, so pardon me if I don't use the right terms.

```
 var myFavoriteDocumentary = {
    "name": "Chronicle of a Summer.",
        "reldate": "1961.",
        "language": "French.",
        "director": "Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin.",
        "getFavFilm": function () {
        return "My favorite non-fiction film is:" + "\n" + this.name + "\n" + "Directed by:" + "\n" + this.director + "\n" + "Year of film:" + "\n" + this.reldate + "\n" + "Language:" + "\n" + this.language;
    }
}
console.log(myFavoriteDocumentary.name);
console.log(myFavoriteDocumentary.getFavFilm());

var dir= "director"

        function dirFake(dir) {
            console.log("The directors are: " + dir);
            dir = "Vertov";
            console.log( dir + " is not the director" );
        }
        dirFake(dir);
        console.log( dir + " are the true directors!" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same procedure that you use to console name.

```
var dir=myFavoriteDocumentary.director;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, just use javascripts bracket or dot notation for objects.

```
myFavoriteDocumentary.directory;
myFavoriteDocumentary["directory"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myFavoriteDocumentary = {
    "name": "Chronicle of a Summer.",
        "reldate": "1961.",
        "language": "French.",
        "director": "Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin.",
        "getFavFilm": function () {
        return "My favorite non-fiction film is:" + "\n" + this.name + "\n" + "Directed by:" + "\n" + this.director + "\n" + "Year of film:" + "\n" + this.reldate + "\n" + "Language:" + "\n" + this.language;
    }
}

console.log(myFavoriteDocumentary.name);
console.log(myFavoriteDocumentary.getFavFilm());

var dir = myFavoriteDocumentary.director;

    function dirFake(dir) {
        console.log("The directors are: " + dir);
        dir = "Vertov";
        console.log( dir + " is not the director" );
    }
    dirFake(dir);
    console.log( dir + " are the true directors!" );
```

sorry for the formatting the log shows following result:

> Chronicle of a Summer. VM178:11
>   My favorite non-fiction film is:
>   Chronicle of a Summer.
>   Directed by:
>   Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin.
>   Year of film:
>   1961.
>   Language:
>   French. VM178:12
>   The directors are: Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin. VM178:17
>   Vertov is not the director VM178:19
>   Jean Rouch and Edgar Morin. are the true directors! 
>   Hope that answers your question.